# Swift 2.2 Error Handeling And Audio

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I am following a tutorial for swift 1.0 (on accident) and it shows how to play a sound. Now in swift 2.0 it wont work please help.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {



var ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cow", ofType: "wav")!)
var ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, error: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
    ButtonAudioPlayer.play();
}

@IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a do-catch statement to handle errors by running a block of code `ButtonAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL)`

```
//ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, error: nil)
do {
    ButtonAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```